# typescript compliment on variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I believe this is available in the typescript doc or SO answer from the past.

But I cannot parse my question correctly to get what I want, so sorry for the re-asking.

I currently encounter a problem to add a type/interface to a variable from a complex 3rd party library that is written in typescript internally and did not export any interfaces nor types. So I have

```
interface KeyProps {
  newKey: string
};
const a = someFunction();
a.newKey = 'somekeyhere'; //ts warning newKey does not exist in XXXXXXX
```

The typescript in the 3rd party library was actually badly rewritten currently. Is there anyway I can simply complement my `KeyProps` without doing something like
`KeyProps & XXXXXX(have to figure out how the typescript is defined in that lib and defined them for my own)`;

I also can do something like `const a = someFunction() as KeyProps;`but I think it's wrong and I lost the typescript definition from that library.

Comment: hmm quick question mate, the newKey is something not existing in the 3rd party and you just added? I find it odd you can override the function of the 3rd party?

Comment: @keysl, it's not a override, it's a compliment, it's really hard to explain the problem but the point to do extend the current variable/class and  the answer got the point,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use typeof to get the type of a, and assign it to a new type so you can create a new variable, like so:

```
interface KeyProps {
  newKey: string
}

const a = someFunction();

type NewType = KeyProps & typeof a;

const b: NewType = {...a, newKey: 'somekeyhere'}
```

Comment: thx a lot, I was able to get the type from `a` based on your suggestion. what I did is `(a as NewType).newKey` because the a itelf is not really a `{ }`

Comment: It would be interesting to see what library you're talking about and how you use it. If it's not an object (ie `{...}`), you can't create a new key on it. You will get an error at runtime.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading. you are right. the return type is an object. The reason I want to avoid spread operator here is actually to slightly boost the performance instead of creating new object. The variable itself is quite heavy. This is just an unusual case, usually I will do the way like you.  I cannot share the code

Comment: Yeah okay, I agree that for performance you should avoid the spread operator. keysl's answer should work though.

Comment: Since you really wonder, I over simply the question for SO, the function also takes another function/component as return, so it's not a direct return. Your solution is more like a band-aid and lazy way to do it, and still remain some of ts benefits at the end. I think at some point I would just use `any` until the typescript was completely upgrade by them at some point (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

I know its solved already but let me give my pitch also, just an alternative.
Basically taking advantage of `typeof` (yeah same with accepted answer) and `ReturnType` and using `as Type` can reproduce that without destruct approach. You can remove the null coallesce for `newkey?:` and that should be fine too
Extending a function like this will give you a bit of leeway on how to define your complimentary props easily too. Without giving the typescripty ability of the functions from 3rd party.

```
 // Lets assume you don't know this 
interface IOldFunction{
    b: string,
    c: string
}

function oldFunction(): IOldFunction{
    return {b:'test', c:'hi'}
}

console.log(oldFunction())

// This will be your code
type P = ReturnType<typeof oldFunction>; 

interface ExtendOldFunction extends P{
    newKey?: string
}

const a = oldFunction()  as ExtendOldFunction
a.newKey = "test";
console.log(a.newKey, a.b, a.c);

console.log(a)
```

[fidde here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBkFMBcGdQIa1gVwLaVATwPYtACY4B2A5NKANbE4Duo0AFgJbwBQzx0kATgGYIAxpgCSAeQA2BAGIpig6MxIBvNqHWgARgC5QsaD04BzADRqNg3fsPEjbAL5s2fOQqXFQOKbPmKSACgBKXXFvVz9iVQ1QHhgUHg9lHXJIfVITUEtSFlJHRzZBElgvSAA6CRwjfy8ZcPcgwKdoLAAHTAAFUABeUAAlOISAFVbIAB5mtpw%20TzDfdwA%20AG5QJ05ufiFMAFEAD25iAklauZJQSD3IA-h2qI1iSFoAaUgsAH4rA2MHJ0LifURujNjm4AoF1EhQLt9odZiDiGwEKV7k8XoCAETcfRoxYFIolcqVfyI5HPLAZRGacmlQSBHG4v74ipVBCBIA)

You can go as far as using the `ReturnType` as extender too like this to make the code shorter

```
interface ExtendOldFunction extends ReturnType<typeof oldFunction>{
    newKey: string
}
const a = oldFunction()  as ExtendOldFunction
a.newKey = "test";
```

Comment: I will use it for other general problems for the future. the complexity of this particular function & typescript are quite terrible that `ReturnType` cannot work properly. otherwise this one is elegant and intuitive.